# jQuery Plugin Scrollorama wrong timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scroll

I made a small example using jQuery Plugin scrollorama:

http://jsfiddle.net/DcSjB/

this is where i call scrollorama:

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var scrollorama = $.scrollorama({
            enablePin:false,
            blocks:'.scrollblock'
        });
        scrollorama.animate('#example1', {
            start:0,         
            duration:400,           
            property:'opacity'
        })
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Now in the docs you can read

"animation is set to begin when the top of the scroll block is at the bottom of browser window"

But the animation starts complete different depending on the width of the screen. I understood the animation should start when .scrollblock start getting into the screen.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Please put your demo on a live service like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net); a raw gist isn't any better than pasting your code here (which you should also do.)

Comment: i could not integrate scrollorama raw js in jsfiddle.

Comment: managed to make a fiddle

Comment: Where is your code? Please see the following: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)...

Comment: should i double post the code thats in jsfiddle...?

Comment: @Mike, [yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code). Only the relevant parts, if you can.

Comment: Per the answer to the link I posted above: _Debug it! Narrow down the problem, to where you can describe it with a useful, searchable title and a small bit of code. Don't just dump your entire page into the question - figure out which portion actually causes the problem, and include just enough code to reproduce it. Don't know how to do this? Ask! Then include a link to a live demonstration of the problem. Don't link to your actual website - use tools like JS Bin or jsFiddle..._

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi there you go
War10ck: allready did (you should see the initial site...)

Comment: @Mike Thanks for posting that. It's much easier to get a grasp on your question when a code snippet is with it. Also less likely to get closed. My apologies though. Wasn't trying to cause trouble just help you out. I removed my downvote. :)

Comment: hmmm, would be nice if someone checks out the problem after all

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say that is because the paragraphs are fluid.  A fixed with will help keep the animation start consistent because when you resize the window the page height is changed.  If you refresh the page with the new width the animation should start consistently relative to the new width and height.

If you want to allow resizing of the browser then I would recommend you re-instantiate the scrollorama for the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a negative delay and that should fix it.

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scrollorama = $.scrollorama({
        enablePin:false,
        blocks:'.scrollblock'
    });
    scrollorama.animate('#example1', {
        delay: -200,
        start:0,         
        duration:400,           
        property:'opacity'
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ce5AP/